# How large an associative array can I pass into an Oracle stored procedure?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Several years ago I wrote an import procedure for an Oracle database, which loads data into a table. The data is passed into the procedure as three separate associative arrays. The import code is written in C# using ODP.Net, and the procedure in PL/SQL.

The customer is now reporting a problem where an expected row is missing from the table. What is the limit on the number of elements or the size of an associative array passed into a stored procedure?

The procedure and array declarations are:

```
TYPE ArrayOfStoreNumber IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(50) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
TYPE ArrayOfStoreName IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(30) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
TYPE ArrayOfStoreType IS TABLE OF INTEGER INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

PROCEDURE ImportDestinationStores(
    pStoreNumbers IN ArrayOfStoreNumber,
    pStoreNames IN ArrayOfStoreName,
    pStoreTypes IN ArrayOfStoreType,
    pCount IN BINARY_INTEGER
);
```

Comment: I wouldn't be looking for the error being in a array size limitation. Oracle would throw an error indicating that you have surpassed a memory or other limit if that were the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can see in the documentation ([*Understanding PL/SQL Collection Types*](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/collections.htm#LNPLS00501)) it is unlimited. So it depends on the memory of your RDBMS.

Answer (score 1):

According Oracle documentation there is no limit. Of course, somewhere the size is limited but you should never reach such limit in reality.

Answer (score 0):

For operations on large collections you should consider using the NOCOPY hint.
Usually parameters are call by value (a copy of the actual variable is passed to the function/procedure) but the NOCOPY hint turns it into a call by reference (the actual variable is passed to the function/procedure).
Same thing applies to the return value.

You just need to extend your procedures signature like this:

```
PROCEDURE ImportDestinationStores(
            pStoreNumbers IN NOCOPY ArrayOfStoreNumber,
            pStoreNames IN NOCOPY ArrayOfStoreName,
            pStoreTypes IN NOCOPY ArrayOfStoreType,
            pCount IN BINARY_INTEGER
);
```

But since you told us that the client is missing data, I wouldn't start searching here. ;-)

Comment: I don't think `NOCOPY` has any effect when you call the procedure from outside via ODP.

Comment: good question xD I think it has because the ODP interface still needs to access the DB and pass these values to the stored proc/func. On the quick I didn't find any information about this. Pretty internal stuff tough xD